# How do you have a text field do dynamic suggestions in the UI from a DB?

Tags: java, database, user-interface, dynamic

I want to have a Java program dynamically suggest list items as a user types in a text field? I want to the suggestions to come from a table in a DB. I might port to Javascript.

I'm not very familiar with SQL, just enough to run simple queries that I need to do. I can normalize simple tables.

The DB will be small (<1000 items), I could have all the data in local storage, and then write an event loop per keystroke to search for the strings, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this generally.

I am open to using some package or other so I don't have to reinvent the wheel, but I would rather write it efficiently myself.

Comment: I think for such a small list set, I would use sqlite3 for look ups and not resort to using big db engine.

Comment: just search for java autocompletion

Comment: Probably, if you have enough memory, you can build a cache in form of trie, so when next character is typed, you'll look up just the subset of trie.

Also, what exact type of text data do you have? Words or more complex expressions?

Comment: @Montreal, categories for a filing system. E.g. "House Records HR-23", "School 2015 SC-2015", "Transcripts T-12"

Comment: @peterk, then trie will work fine. But, before try simpler solutions like using HashMap. I don't think that hitting the DB after each keystroke of each user is a good idea.